# Custom UITableViewController cells won't auto allign

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have some custom cells in a UITableViewController that I've used constraints to set a label to align to the left margin with a a trailing space of 8 and a switch to align to the right margin, also with a trailing space of 8. This looks great on iPhone, but it does not align properly on iPad. Here's what it looks like.

iPhone: [image]

iPad: [image]

How do you set the margin to automatically change based on the screen size so it doesn't look so weird on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely nothing I tried would fix this. It turns out that there must be some bug in iOS9/Xcode 7, because I was only able to fix the issue by downgrading my devices to iOS 8 and Xcode to Xcode 6.